# Axios handle error using interceptor (js promises)

Tags: promise, axios, es6-promise, interceptor

I am using an interceptor in axios to check for errors.

```
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config

    if (!error.response) {
      // No network connectivity
    }
  }
)
```

My request looks like this

```
service.post('endpoint').then(response => {
  // Successful request
}).catch(error => {
  // Handle error
})
```

In case there is any error such as an unsuccessful status code (e. g. 400), I wan't to handle the error in the `catch` part of the second code example. However, if there is a network issue, I wan't to handle the error in the first code example. In that case neither `then`, nor `catch` of the second code example should be called. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that `if (!error.response)` is a good test for no network activity? I can't verify it.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a promise chain already in place you can't stop the flow:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  manageErrorConnection
)

// here you have created a promise chain that can't be changed:
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/user?ID=12345')
  .then(handleResponse)
  .catch(handleError)

function manageErrorConnection(err) {
  if (err.response && err.response.status >= 400 && err.response.status <= 500) {
    // this will trigger the `handleError` function in the promise chain
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Bad status code'))
  } else if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
    // this will trigger the `handlerResponse` function in the promise chain
    // bacause we are not returning a rejection! Just an example
    return 'nevermind'
  } else {
    // this will trigger the `handleError` function in the promise chain
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  console.log(`handleResponse: ${response}`);
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log(`handleError: ${error}`);
}
```

So in order to run an optional step, you need to:

1. put logic in the handler, to skip it
2. put the handler in the chain when it is needed (I would just avoid that since it is "spaghetti software")

---

1. put the logic in the handler example

```js
// .... changing this line ...
    return Promise.reject('nevermind')
// ....

function handleError(error) {
  if (error === 'nevermind') {
    return
  }
  console.log(`handleError: ${error}`);
}
```

This logic could be isolated:

```js
axios.get('http://google.it/user?ID=12345')
  .then(handleResponse)
  .catch(shouldHandleError)
  .catch(handleError)

function manageErrorConnection(err) { return Promise.reject('nevermind') }

function handleResponse(response) { console.log(`handleResponse: ${response}`); }

function shouldHandleError(error) {
  if (error === 'nevermind') {
    // this stop the chain
    console.log('avoid handling');
    return
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
}

function handleError(error) { console.log(`handleError: ${error}`); }
```